# Setar propriedade do model em variável javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho uma Action `Usuario` que exibe detalhes dos usuários entre outras ações que podem ser realizas. Também tenho um código `javascript` que precisa em certa parte setar uma propriedade do model na variável javascript. Segue o código abaixo:

```
@model Aprendendo.Asp.Net.Model.Usuario
//Códigos html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var idUsuario = @Model.Id;
    //Demais códigos
</script>
```

Porém dessa forma não está funcionando. O que fazer nessa situação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colocando aspas na sua propriedade, como exemplo abaixo

```
 @model Aprendendo.Asp.Net.Model.Usuario
 //Códigos html
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var idUsuario = '@Model.Id';
  //Demais códigos
 </script>
```

Comment: Mas isso não funciona quando o código JavaScript estiver em um arquivo externo à view, pois o JavaScript não reconhece a sintaxe do Razor.

Comment: Isso mesmo Ulysses, neste caso seria melhor utilizar a sua solução apresentada abaixo

Comment: Sim, @João Alex. Mas nos casos semelhantes ao da pergunta, em que o código JavaScript está declarado em um Script dentro de uma View, sua solução atende perfeitamente também.

Answer (score 4):

Coloque o valor do model em um campo oculto (`input type="hidden"`) e depois atribua o valor desse campo oculto na variável JavaScript.

Código razor:

```
<input type="hidden" id="codigo" value="@Model.Id" />
```

Código JavaScript:

```
var id = $("#codigo").val();
```